# A dictionary sample in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created a simple hash acting like a dictionary where I want the user to input a word and output the value as definition, but returns an error.

Code example:

```
words = {"Daddy" => "Head of family" , "Mommy" => "Queen of family"}
puts "Enter family member: "
member = gets
puts words(member)
```

Comment: correction : member = gets (and not puts)

Comment: `member = puts` => `member = gets.chomp` ?  And `words(member)` is wrong. You should read some tutorial and learn about the basic first.

Comment: Firstly, please read up on how to ask good questions - it's usual to include the error message that was returned to help others to help you. Secondly, I suggest going through a Ruby tutorial on hashes/dictionarys, e.g. http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: *"but returns an error"* - it does and it tells you that `words` is not a method. The [`Hash` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html) explains how to access a hash. Hint: use `[...]`, not `(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to correct here:

first, use:

```
member = gets.chomp #  chomp removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n)
```

second:

```
puts words[member] # this is how you access a Hash
```

Answer (score 0):

`puts` prints strings and `gets` read strings from your keyboard. So your line

```
member = puts
```

Should be

```
member = gets
```

Comment: it was a typo. Read comments, OP has already mentioned this.